# Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type, even after defining types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript, tsx

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  initialized : boolean,
  onAcceptClicked : ()=>void,
  onRejectClicked : ()=>void,
}
const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = (props:MyComponentProps) => {
}
```

I have defined type using above snippet but still getting Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.

this is similar behaviour with all function parameters

```
(checked:boolean) => {
}
```

this gives Parameter 'checked' implicitly has an 'any' type.

JFYI:

I am using "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1", "typescript": "^3.7.2", with following `tsconfig.js`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,                    /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    /* "strictNullChecks": false,             /* Enable strict null checks. */
    /* "strictPropertyInitialization": false, /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    /* "noUnusedParameters": false,           /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    "alwaysStrict": true,                     /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
//    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,       /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./app/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./bin",
    "./built",
    "**/typings"
  ]
}
```

Comment: [That code doesn't produce that error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgFkBPAYV0mqVoAUcYAM5wA3uThwawGMBQAbYAC8kAEzgAuOACMIEBamoAaSXAjUAgmjRIwMDkrQBrdVrgAKAJQBeAHwAbhDAaqZSFsgAVkgYjsAubtre-kEhpgC+5GgWwvDsXOAWfDDayOgwAHQAYhwAPPncRQJCwn5wPp5gLZoNhbzNECJe7W0SUkQwAK5Q1HC1asABAPR+FOlAA). (That playground does have `noImplicitAny` enabled; I didn't check all of your config settings though.) Perhaps you haven't saved something? Please update the question with a [mre].

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for response, I know this code should not throw that error but I guess this is some issue with at-loader, I wanted to know more about it as I have preconfigured project that uses this configurations, and I have to fix and work with same somehow.